# Java Mutable data structures

Tags: java, data-structures

Why do I keep getting an error when I try to execute this method,

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.function.Predicate;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;

public class BIAOperations <T extends Comparable<T>, E> implements Set<T>  
{


    private HashSet<T> Set;

    public BIAOperations(){
        Set = new HashSet<T>();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty()
    {
        if(Set.isEmpty())
        {
            return true;
        }
        else 
            return false;
    }
    @Override 
    public int size(){
    return Set.size();
}
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Set<T> o) {
        return 0;
    }
    @Override
    public List<T> toList() {
        List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();
        list.addAll(Set);
        return list;
    }
    @Override
    public Set<T> add(T x) {
        Set.add(x);
        return this;
    }
    @Override
    public Set<T> remove(T x) {
        Set.remove(x);
        return this;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean contains(T x) 
    {
        if(Set.contains(x))

            return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
}
```

The error which I get is at the contains method at the bottom of the code.

the error I keep getting is void methods cannot return a value and on else I keep getting syntax error on else delete this token.

Comment: This is not a valid Java method.

Comment: Maybe you want to show us some more code? For example, the overriden method? Also, it would be nice if you could properly indent it. However, I can already tell you this much: You're missing a set of curly brackets. Also, `Set.contains9x` doesn't make any sense, there is no such member in `Set`. What is that supposed to mean/do?

Comment: @domdom That's probably a typo.

Comment: what is `Set` and what is `contains9x` and why do you take `x` as an argument but not doing anything with it inside the method ?

Comment: @UnknowableIneffible maybe, but wouldn't you just copy and paste code instead of actually typing it again for SO? We'll see. :)

Comment: Sorry everyone copied and pasted the code now.

Comment: You implement `Set` and then you create a `HashSet` that you name `Set`. That might be a somewhat bad idea... try renaming that to something like `mySet` or `set` (lower case).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `else` block is outside the method. Fix it as follows:

```
 @Override
    public boolean contains(T x) 
    {
        if(Set.contains(x))

            return true;
       else
           return false;
    }
```

**EDIT**: you can also shorten this code as per @Unholysheep's suggestion in the comment.

```
 @Override
    public boolean contains(T x) 
    {
        return Set.contains(x);
    }
```

Also, as per @domdom's suggestion in the comment, use a better name for your object. In Java, I would recommend you use names starting with a small letter for your objects. Typically, names starting with a upper case letter are used for Class names. So instead of `Set`, use `set` or `customSet` or something for your object.

Comment: Or just `return Set.contains(x);` :)

Comment: I still strongly suggest to rename `Set`. This can and most likely will lead to confusion, at least.

Comment: @UnholySheep, nice suggestion. I edited my answer to include it.

Comment: @domdom. Agreed. Included your feedback in the answer too.

Comment: @AdnanAhmed if this fixed your issue, you should probably mark this as the accepted/best answer.